# How does Ctrl+F5 work in ASP.NET projects in VS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I noticed that when I use Launch Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5 instead of F5) in VS2017, it always works. From desktop applications, I'm used to it failing to build if the application is already running because it can't overwrite the .exe file.

But in my C# ASP.NET WebApi project, when I hit Ctrl+F5, I can make changes to the code and hit Ctrl+F5 again and it will build and run. So I assume Visual Studio manages to close or kill the web application somehow so it doesn't fail to overwrite the file.

Is that how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET enables shadow copying, which copies the assemblies from the bin/ directory into a temp directory before they are executed. That way, the shadow assemblies are locked by the file system, leaving ASP.NET to monitor changes to the bin directory.

You can read more about Shadow Copying Assemblies on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with Visual Studio, but the nature of ASP.NET.

ASP.NET copies the DLL files to a temporary folder in your `Windows` directory. It also compiles the page markup you might have in your folder and copies the generated assembly from that to the temporary folder too. From that folder the web application is ran.

When you change an ASPX file for example, the IIS server recompiles the page files and replaces the DLL. Then it picks up the changes.

When DLL's or the `web.config` are changed, ASP.NET resets the application pool and reloads all assemblies.

Comment: So is that IIS or asp.net? What if I host asp.net application not in IIS?